# dynamically add webbrowser control in windows chat application:

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control, chat

I am developing windows form chat application and i am writing message in richtextbox but when i click on send button and every message show in webbrowser control. .i want to add webbrowser control dynamically for individual message is send.i am using following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{ 
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

          //  this.w1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(w1_DocumentCompleted);
        }
        WebBrowser w1 = new WebBrowser();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Controls.Add(w1);

            HtmlElement div = w1.Document.GetElementById("abc");
            div.InnerHtml = richTextBox1.Text;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            w1.Navigate(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "HTMLPageForScripting.htm"));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the case you asked for:**

- Add a `Panel` to form to put browser in and set its autoscroll property to true;
- In button1 `Click` event, create browser, set its width and height, and navigate to the document you want.
- In button1 Click event subscribe for `DocumentCompleted` event and add content there. We do add here because we should be sure all contents containing `<div id="abc"></div>`has been loaded.

**Here is code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.Height = 100;
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    browser.Navigate(@"D:\test.html");
    browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;

    this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
    //Just do it to put it at the end of list and scroll to it
    browser.BringToFront();
    this.panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(browser);
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    HtmlElement div = browser.Document.GetElementById("abc");
    div.InnerHtml = richTextBox1.Text;
}
```